# Fixed positioning and generated content in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to assemble a fixed-position header out of multiple disparate HTML elements, and for positioning reasons none of them can provide the background bar of color across the top of the viewport.  I have been trying to make up the difference with generated content, which works in Firefox and in IE9, but it runs into trouble in IE8.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IE8 Positioning Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      html:before {
        /* A gray bar across the top of the window */
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 30px;
        background: #cccccc;
        content: " ";
      }
      body {
        margin-top: 35px;
      }
      h1 {
        /* Position the h1 on top of the gray bar */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font: 16px serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Banner text</h1>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec
      a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula
      ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis
      dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet
      vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia
      consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non
      tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a
      semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id
      magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit
      pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero
      in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi
      quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque
      penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
      mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem
      facilisis semper ac in est.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You will need to resize your window (or copy/paste the lorem ipsum several times) so that the page scrolls.  IE8 treats the h1 properly as `position: fixed`, but it seems to be treating the html:before as either `absolute` or `static`.

What can I do about this inconsistency?

Comment: html:before? Seriously? What on Earth are you trying to accomplish? If you want a bar across the top of the window, put it as the first element in the `<body>`. Nothing should come before the html element.

Comment: The bar itself has no semantic value; it's a purely graphical thing, adding it to the markup wouldn't make sense.  And the :before pseudoelement is treated for layout purposes like a part of its owning element -- so it's regarded as the first child of the HTML tag.  That means that other `position: fixed` blocks will naturally stack on top of it.

I'm confident that the markup and the CSS are correct, and they work in modern browsers, including IE9.  It's IE8 that's my problem.

Comment: It is an element in the document, therefore it belongs in the body of the document. If it was an element describing the document or fetching resources for the document (js libraries, etc) it would go in the head. It doesn't matter if it is purely a graphical thing. If this is the case and you wish to keep your markup semantic, use a `<span>` with `display: block;`. Do not put elements other than `<head>` and `<body>` directly within the HTML element. This is most likely the cause of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

> html:before? Seriously? What on Earth are you trying to accomplish? If you want a bar across the top of the window, put it as the first element in the . Nothing should come before the html element.

Maybe that's the source of his problem. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/M314/JQaTG/